# Using Executor Service in Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, executorservice

I want a way to be able to use variables and pass them throughout activities. Essentially, I want keep track of threads between activities and not create new ones as I enter new activities. I'm not sure exactly how to implement this, whether there is a way to pass through the same ExecutorService through android activities or to declare some global class with the ExecutorService as a member where I can use it in any activity.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a way to be able to use variables and pass them throughout activities.

Use bundle with intent to pass variables throughout activities.

> Essentially, I want keep track of threads between activities and not create new ones as I enter new activities.

Going to another activity doesn't create a new thread. This always happens on main thread.

> whether there is a way to pass through the same ExecutorService through android activities or to declare some global class with the ExecutorService as a member where I can use it in any activity.

The question is unclear to me. If you want to use the same background thread in several activities, then you can use a singleton pattern.